# Is there a prime of the form 711...117?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The integers
$$77,\,717,\,7117,\,71117,\,711117,\,\ldots$$
appear to all be composite. However, the lack of a small [covering set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_set) suggests that there might eventually be a prime.

Algebraically, these numbers are given by
$$a_k=\frac{10^k\cdot64+53}{9}$$
for $k\geq1$.

Here is some partial progress:

- A computer search confirms that $a_k$ is composite for all $1\leq k\leq5000$.
- Even though there isn't a full covering set, you can still narrow down the possibilities for $k$. For example, looking modulo the primes $\{3,11,13\}$ shows that if $a_k$ is prime then $k\equiv4\pmod{6}$.

Comment: At least half of them are divisible by eleven because half of them are palindromic numbers with an even number of digits.

Comment: Yes, half are divisible by 11, a third are divisible by 3, and a sixth are divisible by 13 (and you can perform this analysis for any prime).

Comment: there is an entire website dedicated to this problem https://stdkmd.net/nrr/7/71117.htm
I found it by googling the coolest prime factors I could find 237037037037037037039 for the term number 21 and  646464646464646464647 for the term number 22

Comment: @ThomasBrowning the website I mentioned cites two prime numbers of that form, I think that they have been checked using a probabilistic primality test ( I suppose AKS might be impractical for such large numbers). these are the ones with 10905 1s and 499209 1s respectively.

Comment: @mathma That's a clever search strategy! I was getting nowhere with googling "71...17" and variations thereof. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: @ThomasBrowning sure I'll do that :)

Comment: I thought AKS was only important theoretically and not used in practice

Comment: @qwr I am not sure about its use in practice, but I don't know of a deterministic algorithm with lower complexity than AKS.

Comment: So.... if I'm understanding that website correctly, they have not found any primes but have two numbers (large; $k > 5000$) that they believe are probably prime?  Is that correct?

Comment: @fleablood I think so. Although the numbers are almost certain to be prime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I found the following website where the problem is discussed: https://stdkmd.net/nrr/7/71117.htm

The author mentions two (probable) primes, which I assume means they were checked using a probabilistic algorithm

$\frac{10^{10906}\cdot 64+53}{9}=7(1)_{10905}7$ found by Jens Kruse Andersen in 2002 and $\frac{10^{499210}\cdot 64+53}{9}=7(1)_{499209}7$ found by Serge Batalov in 2015.